# alpine linux lighttpd install is missing packages

Tags: linux, lighttpd, alpine-linux

I'm following the documentation here at http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_Up_Lighttpd_With_FastCGI for isntalling lighttpd on Alpine linux but I have a problem when copying the first command:

```
apk add lighttpd php-common php-iconv php-json php-gd php-curl php-xml php-pgsql php-imap php-cgi fcgi
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  lighttpd (missing):
    required by: world[lighttpd]
  php-cgi (missing):
    required by: world[php-cgi]
  php-common (missing):
    required by: world[php-common]
  php-curl (missing):
    required by: world[php-curl]
  php-gd (missing):
    required by: world[php-gd]
  php-iconv (missing):
    required by: world[php-iconv]
  php-imap (missing):
    required by: world[php-imap]
  php-json (missing):
    required by: world[php-json]
  php-pgsql (missing):
    required by: world[php-pgsql]
  php-xml (missing):
    required by: world[php-xml]
scw-f9c40f:~# apk add lighttpd
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Little late to the party but better than never.:)

The problem is that few packages you're trying to install are located in `testing` repository (see `@testing`).

With following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.2
ADD repositories /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk add --update lighttpd@testing php-common@testing php-iconv@testing php-json@testing \
                     php-gd@testing php-curl@testing php-xml@testing php-pgsql@testing \
                     php-imap@testing php-cgi@testing fcgi
```

and `repositories`:

```
http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.2/main
@testing http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

you should be ok.

Comment: At least in alpine 3.7, edit /etc/apk/repositories and uncomment the community repo, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
apk update
```

solved this kind of problem for me.